# Is there a visual proof for why this property of a matrix is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, proof-writing, visualization

Let's say we have three equations written in their standard form:

\begin{align}
a_1x + b_1y + c_1 = 0 && (l_1) \\
a_2x + b_2y + c_2 = 0 && (l_2) \\
a_3x + b_3y + c_3 = 0 && (l_3)
\end{align}

Then if we consider the matrix
$$
M =
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the following is true:
$$
\det M
\begin{cases}
\lt 0 & \text{, if the intersection point of $l_1$ and $l_2$ lies on the "positive" side of $l_3$}\\
= 0 & \text{, if the intersection point of $l_1$ and $l_2$ lies exactly on $l_3$}\\
\gt 0 & \text{, if the intersection point of $l_1$ and $l_2$ lies on the "negative" side of $l_3$}
\end{cases}
$$

I understand why this works mathematically, but I can't find a way that explains it more intuitively. Ideally, I'm looking for a visual proof (e.g. involving some signed volume maybe ?).

Comment: How do you define mathematically "the "negative" side of $l_3$"?Could you give an example with specific values for $a_i,b_i,c_i$?

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen I guess they mean the half plane $a_3x+b_3y+c_3<0$

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Yes, I'm referring to the half-plane like Julio Puerta suggested.

Comment: Can this property actually be true? Assume $\det(M)\neq 0$. If I start with $M$ and then transpose the first two columns, we have not changed any of the three lines $l_1,l_2,l_3$, but we changed the sign of the determinant of the matrix.

Comment: you meant "swap" I guess, not "transpose".

Comment: @zwim Yes, thank you. I meant transpose in the sense of permutations (causing two things to change places with each other), which, in the linear algebra context, is a very bad word choice.

Comment: I think we can probably ignore a correct definition of quoted "negative" and 'positive" in the wording, replace by <0 on one side of l3 and >0 on the other side and save the problem

Comment: My question is indeed worded incorrectly. I swapped the positive and negative sides. Edited.

Comment: @fulk33 It can't be correct either way. Because we can find a single $M$ which corresponds to three lines $l_1,l_2,l_3$, modify $M$ in a way which switches the sign $\det(M)$ but doesn't affect any of the lines $l_1,l_2,l_3$. The only possible case that could be true is $\det(M)=0$ iff $\ldots$.

Comment: I was missing parts of the statement that I was referencing. The original statement is: $sgn(| l_1 l_2 l_3|) \cdot sgn(| n_1 n_2|)$ where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the normal vectors of $l_1$ and $l_2$.

Comment: Should I just create a new question? I'm sorry for butchering this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a visual proof of something that's not true.

There's a problem with talking about "the intersection point of $l_1$ and $l_2$" or "the positive side" of $l_3$. For example, if $a_1=a_2=b_1=b_2=c_1=c_2=0$, $l_1,l_2$ are just the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $a_3=b_3=0$ and $c_3>0$, everything is on the "positive side" of $l_3$.

However, let's ignore that. Consider $$y=0 \tag{$l_1$}$$ $$x=0 \tag{$l_2$} $$ and $$x+y+1=0 \tag{$l_3$}$$ Then we get $$M=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then $l_1$ is just the $x$-axis, $l_2$ is just the $y$-axis, and the intersection is the origin. This is on the positive side of $l_3$, since $1\cdot 0+1\cdot 0+1=1>0$. But $\det(M)=-1$.

However, if we just switch $l_1$ and $l_2$, we get the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$ which has $\det(M)=1$. But we didn't change $l_1,l_2$, or $l_3$, and the origin (intersection of $l_1,l_2$) still lies on the positive side of $l_3$.

Comment: Indeed, this is incorrect. Thanks for the quick disproof.

Comment: I think @zwim's comment is worth pursuing.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is worded, we're looking at the case wherein $l_1,l_2,l_3$ are lines (so situations like $a_1=b_1=c_1=0$ are omitted), and the case wherein $l_1\cap l_2$ is a single point (so $l_1,l_2$ are not the same line).

Let $$h_i=\begin{pmatrix} a_i \\ b_i \\ c_i\end{pmatrix}$$ and let $M$ be the matrix with columns $h_1,h_2,h_3$. Our assumptions that $l_1,l_2,l_3$ are lines and that $l_1\cap l_2$ is a single point imply that $h_1,h_2$ are linearly independent.

Recall that a square matrix has determinant $0$ iff the columns are linearly dependent. With our assumptions above (which imply that $\{h_1,h_2\}$ is a linearly independent set), the columns of $M$ will be linearly dependent iff $h_3\in M:= \text{span}\{h_1,h_2\}$.

Let $(p,q)$ be the intersection point of $l_1,l_2$, so $n=(p,q,1)\in M^\perp$. By considering dimensions, $M^\perp = \text{span}\{n\}$.

We note that $h_3\in M$ iff $h_3^\perp \supset M^\perp=\text{span}\{n\}$ (which is the crux of the argument, I think). But since $h_3^\perp$ is a vector space, it contains $M^\perp=\text{span}\{n\}$ iff it contains $n$, which occurs iff $h_3\cdot n=0$, which occurs iff  $$a_3p+b_3q+c_3=0,$$ which occurs iff the intersection point $(p,q)$ lies on the line $l_3$.